# Displaying popup by clicking on cell

Tags: apache-flex

I have datagrid with populated data. When the user clicks on one particular cell of one column, the popup window has to be displayed, and also same requirement is there for another column.

I could not find how to do it for `cell.doubleclick` and click properties are applicable to row selection. Can any one give solution for this requirement?

Answer (score 0):

Listen to the [itemClick](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flex/3/langref/mx/controls/listClasses/ListBase.html#event:itemClick) event of the `DataGrid` - it dispatches an event of type `ListEvent` that has `columnIndex` and `rowIndex` properties.

If for some reason it doesn't work, you can use a custom `itemRenderer` and dispatch a custom event using its `listData.owner` property.